# Setting Outlook signature for multiple accounts

Tags: c#, outlook

I am in the process of writing an application that sets a signature based on pre-acquired data for each Microsoft Outlook account(a user may have multiple Outlook accounts for various purposes).

I am able to set a signature for the default account, but I have yet to find how to set a signature for each Outlook account individually. I have done a lot of my own research and poked around the Microsoft.Office.Interop objects without much luck.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To choose the Outlook profile programmatically, you just use

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application App =
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
NameSpace mapi = App.GetNamespace("MAPI");
mapi.Logon(profileName);
```

obviously setting the `profileName` to what is shown in the dropdown list upon starting Outlook (if you do not set a default profile in the control panel email settings).

This however is problematic in a number of ways since Outlook does not support multiple sessions even though the MAPI logon does:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219914(v=office.12).aspx

Meaning: if Outlook is already running, you can even set `NewSession` to `true`, but it won't help. It will give you the currently-logged-in profile regardless of what name you set. If you have an Outlook zombie (I got that while testing, check with task manager), i.e. an Outlook without an UI showing up, the problem is the same.

If you can ensure Outlook does not run while doing stuff with signatures, you should be fine though.

Comment: Would I be able to set an Outlook signature for an account with this?

Comment: I would try using the code that sets the signature after creating the session in the way I showed you. I would expect that to result in the desired effect.

Comment: Sadly it only sets the signature for the default account.

Comment: have you checked whether there is no other Outlook process running? I verified that I got the different accounts via this snippet:             `foreach (Account a in mapi.Accounts) {
                Debug.Print(a.DisplayName);
            }` and it indeed returned different mail accounts for the different profiles.

Comment: I have done that, yes. But I haven't found out how to set the signature for individual accounts like that. I'm using Word.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.EmailSignatureEntries.Add()